# Showing that the Edge Cover Polytope is Integral

Tags: combinatorics, convex-optimization, polyhedra, integer-programming

I am struggling with the following question. Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, the edge cover polyope $EC(G) \subseteq \mathbb{R^{|E|}}$ is the convex hull of the incidence vectors of edge covers of $G$.

Here is a Linear Relaxation of the edge cover polytope, which I am trying to show is integral:

(1) For each $v \in V, \sum_{e \in \delta(v)} x_e \geq 1.$

(2) For each $S \subseteq V, |S|$ is odd, $\sum_{e \in E[S] \cup \delta(S)} x_e \geq \frac{|S| + 1}{2}.$

This is a known result, but I cannot find a proof of this fact anywhere except in Schrijver's book. But that is a complicated proof that shows that the polytope is TDI. I just want a proof that it is integral. Can anyone point me to some source for the proof?

How can this problem be reduced to the integrality of the perfect matching polytope?

Comment: $\delta(S)$ is the set of edges with exactly one endpoint in $S$.

Comment: $E[S]$ is the set of edges with both endpoints in $S$. I made the notation involving $x$ explicit in the formulation.

Comment: how about [Theorem 4](https://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438F09/lec7.pdf) (due to Cunningham and Marsh)?

Comment: Cunningham and Marsh result proves that the Matching Polytope is totally dual integral, but I am considering the Edge Cover polytope.

Comment: after spending a good time searching, I do not think a different reference exists